# Customizing Rails 5 collection_radio_buttons to work with Bootstrap 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, form-for

Trying to use Bootstrap 4's form radio component.

Using:

- Rails 5
- Bootstrap 4 (bootstrap_ruby gem)

Like this:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
    Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
    Option three is disabled
  </label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use the `collection_radio_buttons` helper method to achieve this but I'm not having any luck.

Can someone give me an idea how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Currently, I have:

```
<div class="radio">
  <%= collection_radio_buttons(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
     <%= b.label do %>
       <%= b.radio_button %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

It's missing the label name because I'm not sure how to get the label name.

I've tried `label.name` but it's raising an error.

This is the output I'm currently getting:

```
<div class="radio">
<input type="hidden" name="post[category_id]" value="">
<label for="post_category_id_1">
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="post[category_id]" id="post_category_id_30">
</label>
<label for="post_category_id_2">
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="post[category_id]" id="post_category_id_31">
</label>
<label for="post_category_id_3">
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="post[category_id]" id="post_category_id_32">
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`collection_radio_buttons` accepts a block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons), and the method you're looking for is `text`:

```
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
  <div class="radio">
     <%= b.label do %>
       <%= b.radio_button + b.text %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you need option 3 disabled, you could add some kind of model method to check whether it should be disabled or not, and then add something like `<%= b.object.disabled? ? 'disabled' : '' %>` in the `<div class="radio">` tag. Same with the `b.radio_button` call (`b.radio_button(disabled: b.object.disabled?)`).

Comment: Thanks @flanger001 :) b.text did the trick also thanks for referencing the docs.